# Detecting incoming call and opening a service in background on top of the dialer app

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

After detecting the incoming call, I am opening a messenger like chat icon on incoming call. But I am facing two issues :

1.The incoming call is not detected when my application is closed (not running even in background).

2.When my phone is locked, the chat icon does not appear. The chat icon hides behind the dialer app on an incoming call.

I am using `Broadcast Receiver` to receive the incoming call using `PhoneCallReceiver` class which calls methods `defined` under `CallReceiver` class and on detecting incoming call I am starting the service `ChatHeadService` which opens a chat like icon. I have attached screenshot of how the chat icon appears. I have been facing this problem since past 6 months and was not able to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.
compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

targetSdkVersion 23

I tested the app on two devices with API level 18 and API level 26. In API level 18, my app worked fine and both of the above issues were fixed. But in API level 26, my app worked didn't work and the chat icon was hidden behind the dialer app.

I am facing the following error on incoming call in Oreo API 26.
`06-13 16:22:23.969 1238-4375/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } to com.skype.m2/com.skype.nativephone.connector.NativePhoneCallReceiver requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)`

**API level 26**
[image: API level 26]

**API level 18**
[image: API level 18]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.tarun.notifyme2">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SignUp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SendNoti" />

        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <service
            android:name=".ChatHeadService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".MainChat" />
        <activity android:name=".ChatRoom" />
        <activity android:name=".Feedback" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**PhonecallReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import java.util.Date;

public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
            {
                savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
            }
            else
            {
                String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                int state = 0;
                if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
                {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                }
                else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
                {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                }
                else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                }

                onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}

    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number)
    {
        if(lastState == state)
        {
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state)
        {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if (isIncoming)
                {
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context,savedNumber,callStartTime,new Date());
                }

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if(isIncoming)
                {
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

**CallReceiver.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;
import java.util.Date;

public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver
{
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(final Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"New Incoming Call"+ number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        context =   ctx;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("phone_no",number);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ctx.getSharedPreferences("Notify", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("incomingNo",number);
        editor.commit();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //start service which opens a chat icon after 2 seconds wait
                context.startService(intent);
            }
        },2000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end)
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class);
        ctx.stopService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Bye Bye"+ number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**ChatHeadService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int res = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return res;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell2);
        chatHead.setClickable(true);

        params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 400;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

        chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ChatHeadService.this, SendNoti.class)
                                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        //this code is for dragging the chat head
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;
            int flag=0;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    if(flag==3){
                        flag=1;
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        flag=1;
                        return false;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(flag==3){
                        flag=2;
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        flag=2;
                        return false;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    flag=3;
                    params.x = initialX
                            + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY
                            + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    return true;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You ckiced the imageview",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("tag","You clicked the imageview");
                /*
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),SendNoti.class);
                startActivity(i);
                stopSelf();*/
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        /*
        Snackbar.make(chatHead, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();*/

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null)
            windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't want to run application in background then try to look how hike and showing sticker on other application.

Comment: @Jarvis I want my application to run in background. I want the broadcast receiver to work even if my app is closed. But i am not able to so.

Comment: the use startForeground() method to run service in background

Comment: `public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number)` this is not overridden method, you should use an listener to notify that incomming/outgoing calls starts. Let search an examle, where `PhoneStateListener` is extended.

Comment: @grabarz121 can you give me an example or some link?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I found this example. I've added only that, call is incoming or outgoing. Pass your data to the service by intent and use it to perform service. Should work in api 23. In newest versions I can't ensure that.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final static String TAG = "CallReceiver";
private static PhoneCallStartEndDetector listener;
private String outgoingSavedNumber;
protected Context savedContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.savedContext = context;
    if (listener == null) {

        listener = new PhoneCallStartEndDetector();
    }

    String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (phoneState == null) {

        listener.setOutgoingNumber(intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER));

    } else if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

        listener.setOutgoingNumber(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
    }

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}

//Deals with actual events
private class PhoneCallStartEndDetector extends PhoneStateListener {
    int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    boolean isIncoming;
    boolean isOutgoing;
    String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing

    private PhoneCallStartEndDetector() {

    }

    //The outgoing number is only sent via a separate intent, so we need to store it out of band
    private void setOutgoingNumber(String number) {

        savedNumber = number;
    }

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(savedContext, YourService.class);

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        if (lastState == state) {
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }

        switch (state) {

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                isIncoming = true;
                savedNumber = incomingNumber;

                serviceIntent.putExtra("label", value);
                savedContext.startService(serviceIntent);

                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing donw on them
                if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {

                    if (!isOutgoing) {

                        isOutgoing = true;

                    }

                    if (!savedNumber.equals("")) {

                        serviceIntent.putExtra("label", value);
                        savedContext.startService(serviceIntent);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss

                    savedContext.stopService(serviceIntent);

                } else if (isIncoming) {

                    savedContext.stopService(serviceIntent);

                } else {

                    if (isOutgoing) {

                        savedContext.stopService(serviceIntent);

                        isOutgoing = false;
                    }
                }

                break;
        }

        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

}

Register this receiver in manifest, this should work in api 25:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".calls.CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Or register BroadcastReceiver in code, this should work in api 26:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    CallReceiver receiver = new CallReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Of course, to use this code, you need grant permission. In manifest for api level less then 23:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

And for api 23 and newest, ask user about permission:

```
Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Comment: I used my app in a different device of api level 17 and my app worked in that device. So i think the issue is somewhat related to permissions in current api levels.

Comment: I'm understand your application totally doesn't work. Check in oreo device app manager, does your application have granted permissions. From api 23 permissions from manifest doesn't grant automatically, and you must ask user about it (best in launch activity). If permissions are granted, try to register your broadcastreceiver programitically. In api 26 there are limitations about receivers and services. Add some logs in your code and try to register this in launch activity, then make a call.

Comment: I have granted all the permissions my application needs manually on my oreo device. I didn't understand how to register broadcast receiver programmatically.

Comment: `registerReceiver()` or `context.registerReceiver()`

Comment: In which class should i call `registerReceiver` or `context.registerReceiver`?

Comment: I told you, inside launch activity (`MainActivity`?), and try to make call when your app is opened. If your problem will cause here, once registered receiver should work to time, when your app crash/device will be resetarted. I have no idea for app crash, but for device restart, you can use another receiver, with action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and register your receiver there.

Comment: I used the following code in my launcher activity.But it didnt work

                                `CallReceiver myBroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver=new CallReceiver();

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction("Intent.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED");

            registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver,filter);`

Comment: Even after using above code to register broadcast receiver programmatically, incoming call was not detected when application was not running in background in API 26

Comment: I used `intentFilter.addAction("Intent.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED");` as well as `intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");` but it didn't work. I have tested it in both cases on API 26. First when my app runs in background, incoming call is detected but second time when i close my app and then test it, it doesn't detect the incoming call.

Comment: I have updated my question which includes the error which my app faces.Hope it will help

Comment: Updated, but I think it's clear that you need grant this permission.

Comment: But i have given this permission manually on my Oreo device to my app

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409741/permission-denial-with-broadcast-receiver/32420555) answer

Comment: I have also tried using this `android:enabled="true" and android:exported="true"`

Comment: In which receiver permission issue occurs, my or yours? I've finally tested your questions code in emulator, this is not working. Why? Because you have two receivers, but in manifest you have registered just second. Next thing, first receiver is abstract, but abstract keyword is useless, you just extending this class, and his non-abstract methods. All what I did is remove abstract keyword in first receiver, and add to manifest second receiver, but I think you could make this as single class.
ADVICE! Stop using `Toast` in background classes, and start usng `Log.d()` to test your code.

Comment: Next, your service may not run, when app is in background. It's caused by [background limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), so you may need try an another way to run service. Note too, head icon won't show, because you are trying to override device screen using `TYPE_PHONE` which was deprecated in oreo, so you should check an api version, and call `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` to oreo and newest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method after call end

```
private void alert(Context ctx) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 1;");
        //Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

        int number = cur.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
        int duration = cur.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int type = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        sb.append( "Call Details : \n");
        phNumber = null;
        callDuration = null;
        callType = null;
        callDate = null;
        String dir = null;
        String callDayTime = null;
        while ( cur.moveToNext() ) {
            phNumber = cur.getString( number );
            callDuration = cur.getString( duration );
            callType = cur.getString( type );
            callDate = cur.getString( date );
            callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate)).toString();



            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }

//            sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
            sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);

            sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
            Log.e("dir",dir);
        }
        cur.close();

        callType=dir;
        callDate=callDayTime;
        Log.e("call ",phNumber+" duration"+callDuration+" type "+callType+" date "+callDate);

        startactivity(ctx);
    }
```

it will give you last call detail's

Comment: Remember about permission to read call logs `android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG`

Comment: I don't want this method. I already have the details of the incoming call. I want to open chat icon on an incoming call in which I am facing problem.

Comment: in which device you are testing the app?

Comment: @miteshmakwana Api 26 Oreo

Comment: I was testing on different devices

Comment: I mean some device not allow you to use TelephonyManager and background services in the background so you have to manually allow the permission in the app so you have to allow autostart app

Comment: Can i give these permissions in my app?

Comment: check this link    https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-enable-the-auto-start-of-my-app-programmatically